# Chrome developer tools - is there a way to check current's file name?

Tags: php, html, google-chrome-devtools, prestashop

I have a code of online shop on Prestashop, and I have for example content="Shop on PrestaShop" in meta-data of current page, but when I'm trying to find that String in project in Webstorm to localize which page file it is, I get nothing.

So I guess it's some PHP magic working there. So now I have huge problem with finding proper file in order to change that String. Is it possible to check a filename and it's extension via Google developer tools? I'm starting site from server, not localhost.

Comment: If the file name is evident from the URL, then you'd use that.  Otherwise, the names of files used to construct the response isn't information that's generally sent to the client.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html

Comment: Thank you, David, for answer. So I have problem :) @Chris, I've already written, that I've searched my project and I don't have this string, so I guess it's delivered from prestashop's admin's console and some variable in php. Unfortunately I don't know the name of that variable.

Comment: View the html source and look for a string that is fairly unique but not dynamically created next to (or partially including) what you are trying to find and search for that. There are tools like [PHP Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/php-console/nfhmhhlpfleoednkpnnnkolmclajemef) which allow you to inject debug info that you can read in the console, which may or may not help, depending on your environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only find the files that are delivered to client's machine in chrome developers tools by visiting:

```
Inspect > Sources
```

The server side files can be visible only if you can see them in URL. If the path is re-written using something like `.htaccess` in apache, then there's really nothing that you can do to find out the file.

These type of files are meant to be present only to hide the actual file path.